# Transfer SQLite file from android mobile to PC VB.net problem

Tags: android, vb.net, sqlite

use Android Studio easy java code like below

```
package com.George.database;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.File;

public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    int Rcode;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Rcode);
        File exFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download","/easy.db");
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(exFile, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Name text,tel text)");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Name", "Mike");
        values.put("tel", "123456789");
        db.insert("MyTable", null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int R_code, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults[0] == 0) {

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

copy easy.db to PC
write a easy VB.net 2017 SQLite viewer open easy.db error message below
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: File opened that is not a database file file is encrypted or is not a database

use DB Browser for SQLite ,export to sql file then import to SQLite again
run VB.net code again It's OK!!

[image]

Can any one tell me why please ?

Comment: Are you sure the version you are created in AS is the same VS you have created?
Seems exported db is version 3 and you are working in a version 4 in VS. Db browser can open all versions.

Comment: My VB.net2017 System.Data.SQLite version is 1.0.66.0 is it right?

Comment: That is a build number not the version of SqLite engine

Comment: You have to use something in a correct way to genrate your db. You have to extend a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class then on  its constuctor you have to call super class as `super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);`  where DB_VERSION can be a number 3 or 4 deppend on which version you want to create (that's in java).

Comment: you mean db version 1 or 2 or 3? I'll try it these day.

Comment: Yes. 1,2,3 now might be a little older :)

Comment: I use MyDBHander (DB version3 android studio and VB.net same version) but it got the same question!! public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_QUANTITY + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
    }

Comment: If Db browser is able to open the exported file then you have to see in Sqlite connector for .NET specifics. Also in some cases (in failing commits) for some reasons Db remains open there are a file “-journal”  (like .ldb for MS access) that is hidden.